# Spring Boot deploy with Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to deploy **my first Java application** - I have a place to deploy it. I made Spring Boot application with Tomcat. Using some web instruction I make a fat jar file (maven package). I have exceptions. I try to search for it, but any solutions isn't work for this.

What can I add - I do not setup Tomcat, simple base on maven package jar with Tomcat. Could someone tell me what I can do? I will be very grateful for your understanding and help. This is my first deploy.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at pl.foodies.app.AppApplication.main(AppApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1067) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation not permitted
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1064) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you include your application code and configuration?

Comment: Did you develop the application on a windows machine and run it on a linux machine? Do you try to use a well-known port on the machine (like 80)? If that is the case, you need to run the program with superuser privileges. If not, check if the port is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some items to check for here....

1 - Make sure you're including the Tomcat dependency in your POM.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2 - Check to see if your application.properties has the correct port number.

```
server.port=XXXX
```

3 - If this is running on a linux environment, try running the application with the following in your VM:

`-Dserver.port=8181`

4 - Make sure your Application Class extends SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class App extend SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, "hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not configure a valid port, it should > 1024.