# Spring boot with embeded tomcat on AWS is start to fail

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I was able to start it properly with same configuration and port, however suddenly its unable to start with below log. As per the log, its a `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`
However I am surprised that nothing has changed then how suddenly I am getting permission denied, not getting any further clue, can someone suggest please

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)

2021-02-03 10:09:32.282  INFO 26951 --- [           main] c.p.w.e.WebhookEndpointApplication       : Starting WebhookEndpointApplication v1.0.0 on ip-172-31-2
6-225.eu-central-1.compute.internal with PID 26951 (/home/ec2-user/webhook-app/webhook-endpoint/target/webhook-endpoint-1.0.0.jar started by ec2-user in /home
/ec2-user/webhook-app/webhook-endpoint)
2021-02-03 10:09:32.286  INFO 26951 --- [           main] c.p.w.e.WebhookEndpointApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: 
default
2021-02-03 10:09:33.424  INFO 26951 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT
 mode.
2021-02-03 10:09:33.504  INFO 26951 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 72ms. Found 1
 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-02-03 10:09:34.267  INFO 26951 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2021-02-03 10:09:34.283  INFO 26951 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-03 10:09:34.284  INFO 26951 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
2021-02-03 10:09:34.412  INFO 26951 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-03 10:09:34.412  INFO 26951 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2
017 ms
2021-02-03 10:09:34.756  INFO 26951 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], m
ode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2021-02-03 10:09:34.981  INFO 26951 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue
:11}] to localhost:27017
2021-02-03 10:09:34.990  INFO 26951 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with desc
ription ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 8]}, minWireVersion=0, 
maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=6701667}
2021-02-03 10:09:35.550  INFO 26951 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-03 10:09:35.793  INFO 26951 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-02-03 10:09:35.802  INFO 26951 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-03 10:09:35.808 ERROR 26951 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[sprin
g-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring
-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-
2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at com.payon.webhook.endpoint.WebhookEndpointApplication.main(WebhookEndpointApplication.java:10) [classes!/:1.0.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [webhook-endpoint-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [webhook-endpoint-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [webhook-endpoint-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [webhook-endpoint-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:265) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.j
ar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:196) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1066) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1063) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar!/:9.0.34]
... 22 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this answer: [Spring Boot deploy with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668813/spring-boot-deploy-with-tomcat).

In my case; i included the tomcat dependency in the pom file;and I use 8080 as the server pot; which solves my issue.

In addition, don't forget to check your jre and jdk version.